# Slide in/out text on label in titanium

Tags: titanium, uilabel, titanium-mobile, gesture

I have a label which displays dynamic text. For example,  However, I want to add a slide in/slide out feature to the text that appears on the label. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a made an helper library for Titanium animations that you can find here https://github.com/raulriera/Animator

However, if you want to do this yourself "by hand", uou can achieve this using the 2DMatrix API http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.2DMatrix you want to take a look at the translate method (which is the one responsible for moving views)

Comment: and how do I use the library ? Where do I have to add it in order to use the helper library ?

Comment: You can find all the documentation in the github page. Under "Usage"

Comment: where do I have to place the Animator folder ?

Comment: there is no Animator folder, it's a JS file (put it anywhere in your resources). You do know how to use commonJS right? it seems like this is the first time you see Titanium. In that case I will suggest you try more basic stuff first.